# Git overwrite master with a branch

Tags: git

I cloned a repository and created a new branch. Forgot to checkout to new branch. Did the changes (deleted most of the files), added, commited and then pushed to remote. Now I've lost master.

Trying to return to previous state:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard Tony_branch
git push -f origin master
```

Results in:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Processing changes: done
To ssh://<link> can't share the name obviously.
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast forward)
error: failed to push some refs to
```

All answers suggest a "git pull". But it will re delete the files...

How can I fix this?

EDIT:

I am trying to retrieve old master by overwriting it with a branch I created before the changes... other ways might be better of course.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact state of your current repository, and therefore this answer might not work for you, at least not right out of the box.  Instead, I am giving steps which should have been followed as soon as you realized that pushing `master` was a mistake.

First, checkout a new branch from `master` locally:

```
# from master
git checkout -b Tony_branch_real
```

Then, revert the commits you made to `master`:

```
# again, from master
git revert A^..B
```

Here `A` represents the first unintended commit you made to `master`, and `B` represents the last unintended commit.  `git revert` will add a *new* commit to your `master` branch which functionally undoes whatever the (inclusive) range of commits `A` through `B` were doing.  Your actual command would look like more like this:

```
git revert dk93kg93^..k20gjei9
```

where `A` and `B` have been replaced with their SHA-1 hashes.  Check `git log` on your `master` branch to find the required SHA-1 hashes.

Finally, you only need to do a regular push of `master` to the remote:

```
git push origin master
```

This should work because all you have done locally is to add a new revert commit.

The reason we are avoiding doing things like hard reset on `master` is that perhaps this branch is shared by other developers.  Hard reset rewrites history, and therefore this is something we want to avoid for publicly shared branches.

Comment: Can you explain the revert step? how do you revert commit on master from tony's branch?

Comment: @TonyTannous As I mentioned, you may have to do some sorting out on your end to make my answer work.  To answer your comment, from what I understand the current `master` _is_ your Tony branch, because it contains all the commits you intended for the real Tony branch.  So, your main problem here is getting `master` back to the correct state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your remote will not accept a `git push -f`. So unless you can fix the branch protection on the remote (gitlab, github, bitbucket), you cannot undo the master branch.

However you can restore the files you did, in various way. One is to revert all commits, one by one, of master, until you are back to the original state.

Another way is to do

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard origin/master
git reset Tony_branch #soft reset on purpose
git add ... # all changes
git commit -m 'Reverting master to state before bad push'
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 ways to fix a mistake like this.

One way is to do a history rewrite.  This is usually what the person who made the mistake wants, because it undoes the mistake almost entirely.  But it is not always feasible, and sometimes it's just not allowed.

The other options is to accept the mistake as part of history, and add a correction also to the history.

There are at least a couple ways to do each of these.

---

*History Rewriting*

It sounds like you know a suitable way to execute a history rewrite, but it isn't working because of the `push -f` step.  If you control the remote repo, you might be able to change permissions/protection settings to allow a forced push to master, but that's not necessarily a good idea, for two reasons:

First, protecting the master branch is probably a good idea most of the time, even if not in this specific instance.  OF course one could unprotect it, do the rewrite, and then re-protect it, if that were the only concern.

The second possible concern is, if any other clones have already pulled the errant commits into `master`, then force pushing to remove those commits from `master`'s history will "break" those clones and they'll have to take steps to recover.  IF they follow the wrong steps, they could easily re-introduce the removed commits, and this is especially a concern if they have any new work based off of the commits you'd be undoing.  See the `git rebase` docs under "Recovering from upstream rebase"; even though what you're doing isn't a rebase per se, the same situation applies.

So it may well be that you need a solution that doesn't rewrite history, which is what I'll focus on for the duration.

---

*Adding a Correction*

Your repo might currently look like

```
... x <--(tony_branch)
     \
      A -- B -- C <--(master)(origin/master)
```

Now, you'd like to move `origin/master` to `x`; this would make the "cleanest" history.  (And, if we're being honest, it would avoid keeping a permanent record of the slip-up.  This is not to say that we have any reason to keep the record of the mistake; only that wanting to get rid of such a record can *feel* more important than it *is*, weighed against the cost of a history rewrite.)

But you've read this far because apparently rewriting `origin/master`'s history isn't a viable option.  So generally people will suggest using `git revert`.  This would result in something like

```
... x <--(tony_branch)
     \
      A -- B -- C -- ~CBA <--(master)(origin/master)
```

where `~CBA` reverses the changes from `A`, `B`, and `C`, leaving the content (`TREE` object) at `master` just like what was at `x`.  That's one option; it's simple and leaves things in a straightforward state for any future git commands.

Anther option is to use a merge commit for the revert.  This makes `A`, `B`, and `C` look like a side branch that was abandoned.  The "up side' is that it's a little easier to see that `A`..`C` can/should be ignored; the "down side' is that the merge in question will be a bit unnatural - what is sometimes called an "evil merge".  If you're likely to rebase this section of commits, then the "evil merge" could be an issue - but then again, since we go there because history rewrites of `master` aren't a thing, maybe that doesn't matter.  Anyway, this would end up looking more like

```
... x <--(tony_branch)
    |\
    | \---------- Y <--(master)(origin/master)
     \           /
      A -- B -- C
```

To do this, you could say

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard tony_branch
git merge -s ours origin/master
git push
```

Note that whichever way you go about this, commits `A` through `C` are incorporated into `master`'s history.  That means it is no longer possible to "re-apply" your branch's changes by merging those commits into master - because they're "already there".  To fix this, you can create copies of commits `A` through `C` and put those copies on `tony_branch`.  This can be done before or after updating `master` (by revert or by merge); before might be a tad easier, but I didn't include the instructions there because it was easier to explain *why* here.

So what you would do is a "forced rebase" of `A` through `C`.  Contrary to popular belief, `rebase` does not 'replace' the source commits, but rather it copies them.  The force operation just means "make the copies even though I'm not really changing the base or anything else".  The first step is to check out `C`.  How to do that depends on what other steps you've taken:

(A) After applying the merge to `master`, you could

```
git checkout master^2
```

which puts you in detached `HEAD` state on the 2nd parent of the merge commit at `master`.  OR

(B) After instead applying a revert, you could

```
git checkout master^
```

(if the revert was applied in a single commit; it would be something like `master~3` if individual revert commits were used, replacing `3` with however many actual revert commits were used).  OR

(C) *Before* fixing `master`, you could simply

```
git checkout --detach master
```

but note that you *do* want to end up in "detached HEAD" state to avoid incorrect movement of the `master` branch; hence the `--detach` option.

Now having `C` checked out, you can

```
git rebase -f tony_branch
git branch -f tony_branch
```

and you get something like

```
      A' -- B' -- C' <--(tony_branch)
     /
... x ----------- Y <--(master)(origin/master)
     \           /
      A -- B -- C
```

Comment: I wouldn't even bother suggesting the history rewriting option, given that the OP has clearly pushed to the repo (and 99% of readers will probably be sharing that branch with other developers).

Comment: Your preference for incomplete/opinionated answers is noted as always, @TimBiegeleisen

Answer (score 0):

If you are not confident with reset/revert, I would do the below steps instead of doing reset/revert:

(let's assume the branch name you created before the changes is "good-master-branch")

1. Switch your git main branch from master to another (for example, "good-master-branch")

If you are using tools like github, or bitbucket, you can do the setting in the GUI.

2. Delete your current bad master branch

First, make sure you are not on master branch `git checkout good-master-branch`

delete local `git branch -D master`

delete remote `git push origin --delete master`

3. Create a new master branch with the good code

`git checkout good-master-branch`

`git checkout -b master`

4. Set the new 'master' branch as your git main branch

Now, you have a new & clean master branch!